# Python - Advanced Parametric nested loops

Tags: python, loops, recursion, nested

I found great answer on parametric nested loops - [Parametric nested loops in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52839094/parametric-nested-loops-in-python)

However, my requirement is little bit more difficult

**Problem**:

This is 3-depth nested loop (I would like function that has n-depth):

```
for i in range(100 + 1):
    for j in range(i, 100 + 1):
        for k in range(j, 100 + 1):
            -> need to retrieve [i,j,k]
```

Note that each loop's start point is dynamic and changes with every parent loop

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, why not `print(i, j, k)`?

Comment: @olinox14 The question is about arbitrary deep nesting, the 3-depth code is an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a recursive approach using a default argument. The numbered points below refer to the numbered comments in the code.

1. (base) The depth is zero. We are done, so yield the combination, `comb`
2. (inductive) The depth is at least 1. For each `x` in a range, delegate to the recursive generator using `x` as the new starting point for the nested range and append `x` to the combination, `comb`.

```python
def nested_range (depth = 0, start = 0, end = 1, comb = ()):
  if depth == 0:
    yield comb                  #1
  else:
    for x in range(start, end): #2
      yield from nested_range(depth - 1, x, end, comb + (x,))
```

Here's a nested range three (3) levels deep -

```python
for p in nested_range (3, 0, 4):
  print(p)

# (0, 0, 0)
# (0, 0, 1)
# (0, 0, 2)
# (0, 0, 3)
# (0, 1, 1)
# (0, 1, 2)
# (0, 1, 3)
# (0, 2, 2)
# (0, 2, 3)
# (0, 3, 3)
# (1, 1, 1)
# (1, 1, 2)
# (1, 1, 3)
# (1, 2, 2)
# (1, 2, 3)
# (1, 3, 3)
# (2, 2, 2)
# (2, 2, 3)
# (2, 3, 3)
# (3, 3, 3)
```

This implementation is a total function and provides a valid result when `depth = 0` -

```python
for p in nested_range (0, 0, 4):
  print(p)

# ()
```

And for good measure, here's the output of a nested range five (5) levels deep -

```python
for p in nested_range (5, 0, 3):
  print(p)

# (0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
# (0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
# (0, 0, 0, 0, 2)
# (0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
# (0, 0, 0, 1, 2)
# (0, 0, 0, 2, 2)
# (0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
# (0, 0, 1, 1, 2)
# (0, 0, 1, 2, 2)
# (0, 0, 2, 2, 2)
# (0, 1, 1, 1, 1)
# (0, 1, 1, 1, 2)
# (0, 1, 1, 2, 2)
# (0, 1, 2, 2, 2)
# (0, 2, 2, 2, 2)
# (1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
# (1, 1, 1, 1, 2)
# (1, 1, 1, 2, 2)
# (1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
# (1, 2, 2, 2, 2)
# (2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done recursively (as you guessed already) e.g. in this way:

```
def nest_gen(count, start=0, end=101):
    if count < 1:
        return
    elif count == 1:
        yield from ((r,) for r in range(start, end))
        return

    for i in range(start, end):
        yield from ((i,) + r for r in nest_gen(count - 1, i, end))


print(tuple(nest_gen(6, end=5)))
```

Comment: I like this solution more than my answer - it's exactly the same logic, but much more pythonic

Comment: Non-total function. Causes stack overflow when `count = 0`.

Comment: You're welcome but the codomain is still non-total. Please see the comment I made on Green Cloak's post for details.

Answer (score 2):

This is the kind of thing that I would use recursion for - as I see you've noted in your tag. Something like this, for example:

```
def iterate(depth, i=0, maxrange=101):
    if depth <= 0:
        return (yield ())
    for j in range(i, maxrange):                    # for each value of j...
        if depth == 1:                              # base case:
            yield (j,)                              #    return a 1-tuple
        else:                                       # recursive case:
            for k in iterate(depth-1, j, maxrange): #    get a generator for the next level of recursion
                yield (j,) + k                      #    yield all (depth+1)-tuples from prepending j to the next layer of recursion
```

which, when called as `iterate(3)` should produce

```
[(0,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,0,2), ..., (0,0,100), (0,1,1), ..., (0,100,100), (1,1,1), ..., (99,99,99), (100,100,100)]
```

Comment: syntax error on your first line, missing `:`. program gives bad result when `depth=0` is specified.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I've done my best to address it

Comment: it's close but the codomain (possible outputs) is a bit off. You probably want `return (yield ())` otherwise `depth = 0` gives _no_ result instead of an _empty_ result. To understand why this is an issue, imagine if `subtract(5,5)` returns nothing (`None`) instead of `0`, the "empty" number. The function depending on `subtract`'s output would have to check if it received a value. By returning an "empty" value, the caller of `subtract` is guaranteed that a result will always be returned.

Comment: @user633183 Thanks, I've changed it accordingly. Would returning `tuple()` work as well?

Comment: `return (yield tuple())` would be equivalent, yes.

Comment: @user633183 What a generator `return`s can be completely different from  (and is usually of less interest than) what it `yield`s. I don't understand why it has to fulfill a particular requirement here.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an iterative approach:

```
def iterate(max_range, dim):
    if dim == 0:  #handle edge case
        yield from iter(())
    elif dim == 1:
        yield [0]
    else:
        fields = [0]*dim
        while True:
            yield fields
            fields[-1] += 1
            for i in reversed(range(1, dim)):
                if fields[i] >= max_range:
                    fields[i - 1] += 1
                    fields[i] = min(fields[i - 1], max_range -1)
            if fields[0] == max_range:
                break
```

an example:

```
for i in iterate(4, 3):
    print(i)
```

gives:

```
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 3]
[0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 3]
[0, 2, 2]
[0, 2, 3]
[0, 3, 3]
[1, 1, 3]
[1, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 3]
[2, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 3]
[3, 3, 3]
```

edit:
added separate parameters for max_value and nesting level

Comment: I don't believe this fits the OP's requirements. The nesting level and the range max are two separate variables.

Comment: Nice update but one problem remains. If `dim = 0` your program throws an error instead of returning a valid result. See the comments in GreenCloak's answer for more details.

Comment: If you consider dim = 0 as an valid input, then you are right. But it should not be to hard to check for dim == 0 and return an empty iterator or whatever is considered meaningful in this case.